# RewriteRule comes back to the same directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make two rewrite rules which should point to different files. However, they somehow are pointing to the same PHP file.

Can somebody help take a look please?

---

```
RewriteRule ^destinations/([a-z]+)-(.*)$ /a.php?x=$1&y=$2 [NC]
```

This should be linked to `www.example.com/destination/us-united-state`

---

```
RewriteRule ^destinations/([a-z]+)-(.+)-(.+)$ /b.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [NC]
```

This should be linked to `www.example.com/destination/us-united-state-california`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression finds the longest possible match.  So, `([a-z]+)-(.*)$` will match one or more a through z characters followed by a dash followed by ANYTHING.

`([a-z]+)-(.+)-(.+)` requires two dashes, but the above expression will match these too.

be sure that you have the correct number of dashes matched:

```
RewriteRule ^destinations/([a-z]+)-([^-]+)$ /a.php?x=$1&y=$2 [NC]
```

and rename the page to

```
www.example.com/destination/us-unitedstate
```

then

```
RewriteRule ^destinations/([a-z]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)$ /b.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [NC]
```

to match pages like

```
www.example.com/destination/us-unitedstate-california
```

Comment: Your first rule still matches `www.example.com/destination/us-unitedstate-california`. Use `[^-]+` instead.

Comment: thanks you for the lighting reply. I'll try it yr suggestion!

Comment: Oops, yes, should use [^-]+ for anything but -  Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an other delimiter between `us` and `united-state` and between `united-state` and `california`. There is no way you can detect if the three seperate words in `www.example.com/destination/us-united-state` are actually two or three 'things'. I advice using slashes as delimiter instead: `www.example.com/destination/us/united-state` and `www.example.com/destination/us/united-state/california`.

Your rules would be:

```
RewriteRule ^destinations/([a-z]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /a.php?x=$1&y=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^destinations/([a-z]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /b.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [NC]
```

This uses `[^/]+`, which matches anything but the `/` character. This prevents a capturing group from matching something like `us/united-states` where it should only match `us`. Please note that this code is untested as I can't test on this computer.